# problem adding a where clause to a T-sql LEFT OUTER JOIN query

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.EmployeeInfo.id, MIN(dbo.EmployeeInfo.EmpNo) AS EmpNo, 
            SUM(dbo.LeaveApplications.DaysAuthorised) AS DaysTaken
FROM  dbo.EmployeeInfo LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.LeaveApplications ON 
           dbo.EmployeeInfo.id = dbo.LeaveApplications.EmployeeID
WHERE (YEAR(dbo.LeaveApplications.ApplicationDate) = YEAR(GETDATE()))
GROUP BY dbo.EmployeeInfo.id, dbo.EmployeeMaster.EmpNo
ORDER BY DaysTaken DESC
```

The basic functionality i want is to retrieve all records in table dbo.EmployeeInfo irrespective of whether a corresponding record exists in table dbo.LeaveApplications. If a row in EmployeeInfo has no related row in LeaveApplications, i want to return its  `SUM(dbo.LeaveApplications.DaysAuthorised) AS DaysTaken` column as NULL or may be even put a 0.

With the above query, if i remove the where condition, am able to achieve what i want, but problem is i also want to return related rows from LeaveApplication only if ApplicationDate is in the current year.

Now with the where condition added, am only able to get rows from EmployeeInfo only if they have corresponding rows in LeaveApplications yet i just wanted rows all in EmployeeInfo

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is no corresponding `LeaveApplications`? What should it do in the where clause for the returned rows?

Comment: if there is no LeaveApplications, i still want to return all rows in EmployeeInfo, and then assign a NULL value or even 0 to dbo.LeaveApplications.DaysAuthorised query result column.

Comment: May be i should add that even if there are 0 related rows in LeaveApplications, i still want to retrieve all records in EmployeeInfo and then show 0(Zero) for the "DaysAuthorised" column for each returned row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a test for `NULL` in your `WHERE` clause, this can cause your `SUM` to return `NULL` as well for rows that do not exist on the `LeaveApplications` table:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.EmployeeInfo.id, MIN(dbo.EmployeeInfo.EmpNo) AS EmpNo, 
            SUM(dbo.LeaveApplications.DaysAuthorised) AS DaysTaken
FROM  dbo.EmployeeInfo LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.LeaveApplications ON 
           dbo.EmployeeInfo.id = dbo.LeaveApplications.EmployeeID
WHERE (YEAR(dbo.LeaveApplications.ApplicationDate) = YEAR(GETDATE()))
      OR dbo.LeaveApplications.ApplicationDate IS NULL
GROUP BY dbo.EmployeeInfo.id, dbo.EmployeeMaster.EmpNo
ORDER BY DaysTaken DESC
```